# XSLT transform/mapping work - what questions will you ask?

Tags: mapping, schema, xslt-2.0

I have been given an assignment. It pertains to integration/transformation using xml/xslt and is deliberately vague.  I have been given a sample integration (shown below) and I have been tasked with listing several questions I would ask before delivering this design,

#### The hypothetical integration

```
Data Source --> Mapping ---> output
```

The question is so vague I couldn't think much. I am not looking for anyone to plagiarise from, but I am hoping someone could post some sample questions to help me get started.

Comment: I'm quite sure they expect **you** to come up with the questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too broad, or because OP shouldn't cheat on a test, or because it's too opinion-oriented.

Comment: I think Its too harsh to say its cheating . Obviously I have obviously my opinion an . I have just asked what can other possible good answers. again its not like i have to write answer and send them. it would be discussed during process and obviously my answers would depend on the on time questions at  that time.

Comment: I am giving you the benefit of the doubt and have updated the question to make it sound less like you are a cheater.  After reading the question and seeing your username I believe there is a language barrier here, so I am trying to give you the benefit of the doubt and assist you rather than close the question altogether

Answer (score 3):

### Pertinent Information

> **Note**: Stack Overflow is not a place for you to cheat on an interview process.  I am providing this information for other users who are looking to familiarize themselves with integrations.  If you don't already know what questions to ask here, and are applying for an SOA job, you will likely be fired within a month.  Dishonesty can cost a business a lot of money, and if you cheat your way into a job don't be surprised when you get blackballed or worse - perpetuate a harmful stereotype.

There are a variety of questions you would need to ask before implementing this type of integration. Here are a few things that come to mind.

#### 1. What type of integration is this?

There are a variety of different integration paradigms.  I would need to know if it is

- An app/request driven orchestration
- A scheduled orchestration
- A file transfer
- A pub/sub subscription

#### 2. Is it invoked or triggered

An invoked integration is one that begins when it is specifically called.  If I had a REST service that returned a list of countries, and your call that service every time a button was clicked that would be an invocation based integration.

Integrations can also be trigger based.  Let's say you had a table that stored customers.  You want to send an email whenever a new customer is added to that table.  If you set your initial data source (adapter) as a trigger source on a row insert you could essentially have the integration run without explicitly being *triggered*.

#### 3. What is the data source?

I would need to know if the data source is REST, SOAP, a database (DB2, MySQL, Oracle DB, etc), a customer adapter, etc.  IS the data source adapter the entry point here or is the initial app adapter not shown?

#### 4. What is the schema definition of the request / response body, and how is it specified?

You have a data source (which appears to be your initial app adapter), then you have a transformation, and a response.  You can't do any transformation (or build an integration) if you don't know what the input / output will be (with some exceptions).  This is really a multi level question.

1. How do I specify the request and response?  Do I need to draft a JSON Schema or XSD document?  Some platforms allow you to specify XML or JSON and they will do it's best to generate a schema for you.
2. What is the request and response content type?  You can specify the request / response in whatever format is acceptable, but that doesn't necessarily mean that is the request / response type.  For example some platforms let you specify your request body with an XSD but the content type is actually JSON.  Is it XML, JSON, Plain Text, other?

#### 5. What about other parameters

Basically, what does the endpoint look like?  Are there query parameters, template parameters, custom header parameters, etc?

#### 6. How is this integration secured?

Is this integration security using OAuth?  If so what type of tokens are used (JWT, etc)? Does the integration use basic authentication?

Based off the answers to the previous questions you may then have questions about the mapping. For example, if I was provided a schema definition for the output that had an attribute called "zip" I might ask how they wish to format that, etc.  I wouldn't ask anything about what technology is used for the mapping.  Firstly, because it'as almost always XPath/XSLT, secondly that isn't something you need to know, it's something you would figure out on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The intention of asking question here was not of cheating but to add more to my knowledge in terms of what i can think of. i think here my way of asking question is wrong. I should have added my points which i can think of and should have asked if more points anyone can think of. if i would not have mentioned interview here these cheating would not have came into picture :). About getting Fired , i don't think i would get selected anywhere based on answer of one small assignment . various criteria is taken into consideration before any company hires someone :)

Comment: Definitely its not a SOA job. About language barrier, my mother tongue is not english

Comment: Ok hope my post helped. If there is anything I didn't address let me know and I will do my best to respond